# Display audio name in progress bar

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to Display current playing audio name in progress bar
from audio.js

```
<div id="audio_tag" style="display:none">
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-7 audioshow"> 
    <div class="play-pause "> 
        <p class="play"></p> 
        <p class="pause"></p> 
        <p class="loading"></p> 
        <p class="error"></p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="scrubber col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-5"> 
        <div class="progress" id="progress"></div> 
        <div class="loaded"><span class="color" id="audionamloaded"></span>
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="time"> 
        <em class="played" id="tym">00:00</em>/<strong class="duration" id="duration">00:00</strong> 
    </div> \
    <div class="error-message"></div> 
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5">
    <i class="fa fa-backward fbutton" id="bwd"> </i><i class="fa fa-forward fbutton" id="fwd"></i> 
    <i class="fa fa-step-backward fbutton" id="skip-bwd"></i> <i class="fa fa-step-forward fbutton" id="skip-fwd"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-download fbutton" onclick="download()"></i>
 </div>
</div>
```

is loaded in which `<span class="color" id="audionamloaded"></span></div> \` name will display here but when progress bar increase name will b hidden..I want to show that name..

here is http://jsfiddle.net/4gwvqj0s/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="progress" id="progress">
  <span class="color" id="audionamloaded">Name Of Song</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working on your fiddle: <div class="progress" style="width:2;">Test</div>

I edited the code above by the way.

Comment: can u provide me jsfiddle?

Comment: I edited it with developer tools, could you instead provide the full html for your page inside the fiddle?